# postgreSQL 13: Starting the Database Server on windows 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

The documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/server-start.html offers this command:

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

But with this command I get the following error:

> Running the PostgreSQL server by a user with administrator rights is not allowed.
> The server must be started with an unprivileged user to prevent
> any security issue on the server. See the documentation for
> more information on running the server clean.*

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `pg_ctl` to start the Server - that ensures that the administrator privileges are dropped during startup.

Something like:

```
pg_ctl -D c:/Data/PostgresData start
```

You can register Postgres a Windows service using `pg_ctl`

The parameters are documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html#APP-PG-CTL-WINDOWS-OPTIONS)

```
pg_ctl register -N postgresql-13 -D c:/Data/PostgresData
```

That must be done with Administrator privileges.

By default the service is set to automatic start, you can disable that if you want. Then you can start it manually using:

```
net start postgresql-13
```

(Again with a privileged Administrator account)

Comment: Please can you put a link that explains how to install postgres as a Windows service ? The documentation shows several ways to install it.

Comment: @DONGMOBERNARDGERAUD: `pg_ctrl register ...`  as explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. All commands `$pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" option` are working now. After launching the command `$pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" start`, the services.msc shows that **postgresql-x64-13 - PostgreSQL server 13** is running.

Comment: Putting the data directory  (or actually _any_ application data) below `c:\Program Files` is a really bad idea.

Comment: You're right, I had already had some problems with that on android sdk.